# How to cope with scatter matrices of a lot of features?

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, scatterplot

Pandas `scatter_matrix` is a great tool for finding correlation between different features - but it's only readable if the number is small. What way do I have to find correlations between features when the number of features rise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could plot a [correlation heatmap using seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) (see the very last example) or if you're using Jupyter you can try [lens](https://github.com/asidatascience/lens) which is supposed to create an interactive widget to let you cycle through density plots of each variable pair.